# Use first available number from a file

Tags: bash, shell-script, numbering

I have a config file `prosody.config`

With the following data:

```
VirtualHost "pubsub.subdomain.domain.com"
admins = { "node1.subdomain.domain.com", "node2.subdomain.domain.com" }
    autocreate_on_subscribe = true
    autocreate_on_publish = true
    modules_enabled = {
        "pubsub";
    }

VirtualHost "subdomain.domain.com"
    authentication = "anonymous"
    modules_enabled = {
        "bosh";
    }
    c2s_require_encryption = false

VirtualHost "auth.subdomain.domain.com"
    authentication = "internal_plain"

admins = { "focus@auth.subdomain.domain.com" }

Component "node1.subdomain.domain.com"
    component_secret = "password"
Component "node2.subdomain.domain.com"
    component_secret = "password"
Component "conference.subdomain.domain.com" "muc"
Component "focus.subdomain.domain.com"
    component_secret = "password"
```

I need to find the first available number after the `node2.subdomain.domain.com` in this case number `3` and echo it back to the same config like `echo -e "Component \"node3.subdomain.domain.com\"\n
component_secret = \"password\"" >> prosody.config`

The final content should look like this:

```
VirtualHost "pubsub.subdomain.domain.com"
    admins = { "node1.subdomain.domain.com", "node2.subdomain.domain.com" }
        autocreate_on_subscribe = true
        autocreate_on_publish = true
        modules_enabled = {
            "pubsub";
        }

    VirtualHost "subdomain.domain.com"
        authentication = "anonymous"
        modules_enabled = {
            "bosh";
        }
        c2s_require_encryption = false

    VirtualHost "auth.subdomain.domain.com"
        authentication = "internal_plain"

    admins = { "focus@auth.subdomain.domain.com" }

    Component "node1.subdomain.domain.com"
        component_secret = "password"
    Component "node2.subdomain.domain.com"
        component_secret = "password"
    Component "conference.subdomain.domain.com" "muc"
    Component "focus.subdomain.domain.com"
        component_secret = "password"
    Component "node3.subdomain.domain.com"
        component_secret = "password"
    Component "node4.subdomain.domain.com"
        component_secret = "password"
```

Every time you run the script the number increases by one from the biggest number in this case `"node4.subdomain.domain.com"`

Thanks !

Comment: and why *node4* should become available?

Comment: because it's the first number after 3 which is not present in the file, the next would be node5 and so...

Comment: If the file had just `node1` and `node3`, what should the output be?

Comment: there will be no case like that, but it should continue with the highest number in this case `node4`

Comment: updated my question, sorry for confusion

Comment: @DaWe4444, there are multiple lines containing `node1 .... node2` values in your input. Which section exactly should be considered? Ans how should look the final result after echoing back?

Comment: @DaWe4444, I can help if you post the whole final content after replacement

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I have updated my post, thanks a lot !

Comment: @DaWe4444, I see `node3` and `node4` appended. Should it append to the end of the file on each script running?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest that is correct.

Comment: @DaWe4444, I can suggest Python 3 solution

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest nevermind I have solved this out differently.

Answer (score 1):

Short ***gawk*** solution:

```
awk -v FPAT="[0-9]+" 'END{print "node"$1+1}' xyz.config
```

The output:

```
node4
```

---

- `FPAT="[0-9]+"` - a regexp that matches the fields, instead of matching the field separator
- `END{...}` - considering only the last line of the file

Comment: The problem is that there is additional text after `node3`, it's like `node4.domain.com`

Comment: @DaWe4444,  you mean the if the last line is `node3.domain.com` the output should be `node4.domain.com` ?

Comment: these entries are not present at the last line they are in random places. Yes the output should be `node4.domain.com`

Comment: what do you mean with *in random places*, can you update your question with actual input example?

Comment: updated my question, sorry for confusion

Answer (score 0):

```
< xyz.config tail -n 1 | awk 'match($0, /[0-9]+$/) {
  print substr($0, 1, RSTART-1) substr($0, RSTART)+1}'
```

To get the last line of the file, extract the digits at the end of the line, prints what precedes the digits followed by the number making up those digits incremented by one.

You can also do the whole thing in `awk`, but that means reading the whole file fully:

```
< xyz.config awk 'END {if(match($0, /[0-9]+$/))
  print substr($0, 1, RSTART-1) substr($0, RSTART)+1}'
```

Using `sh` operators:

```
< xyz.config tail -n1 | (
  IFS= read -r line || exit
  num=${line##*[!0-9]}
  printf '%s\n' "${line%"$num"}$((num + 1))")
```

Comment: actually the whole file is better, since there will be other config directives which has no relevance for this.

Comment: @DaWe4444, I meant that `tail` will go straight to the end of the file (using `lseek()`) while using the `END` statement in `awk` alone means `awk` will read the whole file (and do nothing about it except storing each line in turn in $0) before we process the last record in `END`. On a big file, `tail`+`awk` would be more efficient. For small files, running an extra `tail` command will be more overhead than reading the file fully.

Comment: updated my question, sorry for confusion